# Why does the `AlternateScreen` require pressing Enter when reading an input key?

Tags: rust

I have created a simple command line tool using the [termion](https://github.com/redox-os/termion) crate in Rust. It prints a "Hello world!" message when a key is pressed. It quits the program only if the input is the `q` character. Here is the code that uses the `AlternateScreen` struct to write on the terminal:

```rust
use std::io::{stdin, stdout, Write};
use termion::event::Key;
use termion::input::TermRead;
use termion::raw::IntoRawMode;
use termion::screen::IntoAlternateScreen;

fn main() {
    // Initialize stdout and stind
    let stdin = stdin();
    let mut stdout = stdout().into_alternate_screen().unwrap();

    // Print a message indicating what to do
    write!(
        stdout,
        "{}{}Press any key to print 'Hello world!', or press 'q' to quit.{}",
        termion::clear::All,
        termion::cursor::Goto(1, 1),
        termion::cursor::Hide
    )
    .unwrap();
    stdout.flush().unwrap();

    // Create an input reader for key events
    let mut row = 1;
    for c in stdin.keys() {
        write!(
            stdout,
            "{}{}",
            termion::cursor::Goto(1, row),
            termion::clear::CurrentLine
        )
        .unwrap();

        match c.unwrap() {
            Key::Char('q') => break,
            _ => println!("Hello world!"),
        }

        stdout.flush().unwrap();
        row += 1;
    }

    // Enable back the cursor
    write!(stdout, "{}", termion::cursor::Show).unwrap();
}
```

I write the message to a new line by going to the next row and the first column. The `row` variable tracks where to write the next message.

The problem is that I have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to register the characters in the standard input. However, an additional "Hello world!" text is appearing because of the extra <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. I would like to write the text immediately after any input key, without the need to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button.

Note that if the standard output is replaced with the `RawTerminal` struct, everything is working as expected.

```
let mut stdout = stdout().into_raw_mode().unwrap();
```

In this case, it is not necessary to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the input character.

Why does the `AlternateScreen` require pressing Enter when reading an input key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're experiencing with the `AlternateScreen` struct is due to how terminal buffering works. In canonical mode, the terminal buffers input until it encounters a newline or EOF character. The `RawTerminal` struct puts the terminal into raw mode, where input is not buffered and is instead sent directly to your program.

In your case, when you're using `stdout().into_alternate_screen()`, your terminal is still in canonical mode and therefore requires the Enter key to be pressed before it sends the input to your program. This is why you see an extra "Hello world!" message when you press Enter.

On the other hand, when you use `stdout().into_raw_mode()`, your terminal is in raw mode, and it sends input directly to your program without waiting for a new line or EOF. This is why you don't need to press Enter in this case.

To fix your issue, you need to put your terminal into raw mode while using `AlternateScreen`. You can do this by chaining `into_raw_mode()` after `into_alternate_screen()`:

```rust
let mut stdout = stdout().into_alternate_screen().unwrap().into_raw_mode().unwrap();
```

Comment: I have found the [alternate_screen_raw.rs](https://github.com/redox-os/termion/blob/master/examples/alternate_screen_raw.rs) example in the termion repository that uses different conversion order: `stdout().into_raw_mode().unwrap().into_alternate_screen().unwrap()`. Is it the same as converting to an alternate screen and then into raw mode?

Comment: The order of calling `into_raw_mode()` and `into_alternate_screen()` does not matter. These methods return different types, but they don't affect each other's behavior.

Comment: You need to `unwrap` or `expect` after the `into_alternate_screen` method because it returns with a `Result` type.